# can't find referenced method 'android.widget.ProgressBar access$400'

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm getting the following error when generating signed APK via proguard:

```
Warning:com.package.myactivity$1$1: can't find referenced method 'android.widget.ProgressBar access$400(com.package.myactivity)' in program class com.package.myactivity
```

Here is my proguard configuartion:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** e(...);
public static *** w(...);
}
```

app.gradle:

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Any pointers to fix this issue is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your `View` classes. It can be done with the following rules:

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even with this. Please help.

Comment: Try adding `-dontwarn android.widget.*`.